# How to connect with JMX remotely to Spark worker on Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I can connect to the driver just fine by adding the following:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
                              -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9178 \
                              -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                              -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

But doing ...

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
                                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9178 \
                                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

... only yield a bunch of errors on the driver ...

```
Container id: container_1501548048292_0024_01_000003
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

... and finally crashes the job.

There are no errors on the workers, it simply exits with:

```
[org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager] - Shutdown hook called
```

`Spark v2.2.0`, and the cluster is a simple 1m-2w-configuration, and my jobs run without issues without the executor parameters.

Comment: Have you checked, that the ports are free? If those executors get instantiated on the same machine, the port collisions spell trouble.

Comment: Conflicting ports on the worker seems to be the source for the crash, indeed. However, how do I control this otherwise? Setting it to `0` will give me a random one. Is it possible to pass different args to different executors?

Comment: I would recommend setting the executor memory large enough, that only one will fit on each machine. You may have to adjust your resource manager settings as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Rick Mortiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6320293/rick-moritz) pointed out, the issue was conflicting ports for the executor jmx.

Setting:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0
```

yields a random port, and removed the errors from Spark. To figure out which port it ends up using do:

```
netstat -alp | grep LISTEN.*<executor-pid>/java
```

which lists the currently open ports for that process.

Answer (score 1):

Passing following configuration with spark-submit worked for me 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9178 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"